# Firebase Messaging : Successful but not delivered

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a Device Group in firebase Messaging - [Documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group)  and got back the `notification_key`

Now when I use that `notification_key` to send messages using Firebase Console, they are sent and delivered to all registered devices.

[image]

But doing the same thing outside the console (for example in postman) does not work, I do however get a success message for all devices and zero failures but the devices never receive the message.

**Response in Postman**

```
{
    "success": 7,
    "failure": 0
}
```

**My post request** is the following

```
curl -X POST \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \ 
  -H 'Authorization: key=***' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \  
  -d '{
  "to": "my_notification_key",
  "data": {
   "hello": "test  !"
   }
}'
```

I feel like I am missing something but as per [provided documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group) that all it should need to send a message

**From Firebase Documentation**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "aUniqueKey",
  "data": {
    "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!",
   }
}
```

any idea what is going wrong here as I receive success message but the message is never delivered to the devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to pass the `notification` instead of just 'data' as following

```
"to" : "notification_key",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thats works fine but where can we pass data and custom properties ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes you can send data with custom properties, please use "data" instead of "notification" then you can add any custom property such as `"body": "this is the body" , "email": "email@com.com", "payload": "<JSON>"` I personally use one property and call it `payload` and pass all the needed data in Json format.. hope this help

Comment: You save mine day ^^ Good job